# what should I do I am unable to install anything?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, matlab

```
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up matlab-support (0.0.21) ...
No default Matlab path found. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package matlab-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 matlab-support
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[image]

Comment: The system is asking you TWO questions. One is on the GUI (interface config path). The other is in the Terminal (MATLAB source repo not found). Answer both in any order you please.

Comment: Use the tab key to navigate to "OK" and hit enter in the terminal.